# HTML5 Application is not synced with hana cloud database

Tags: database, hana

we have created a simple cap project and deployed from bas to clous foundry. The deployment was successful without any error.
When we try to launch the HTML5 application the column heading is visible with empty data. there is no existing entries are available. Looks like the Hana Cloud database is not synced with HTML5 application to get the entries from database.

Please guide me here to fix the issue.

Thanks in Advance

I want to get the entries synced with HTML5 application with all the data.